# Identifying feature of page inspector (Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

[image: inspector console output enumeration]

What are the highlighted number bubbles representing in this picture of my Chrome browser console output?

(In the code I'm iterating over some elements in HTML being returned by an AJAX call. I'm guessing it is counting the iteration or something.) Couldn't find it in the DevTools documentation.

Thank you!

Comment: Messages with the exact same text are stacked together. You can disable this feature by turning on 'Show timestamps' in the DevTools settings. More here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706235/chrome-debugger-how-to-turn-off-console-log-message-grouping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers represent the number of times that piece of code was run. So, 2 times it ran the line  `entered disabledOb...` where ever that console.log is, and so on.

I have created an issue for adding this to the docs too here https://github.com/GoogleChrome/devtools-docs/issues/198