# How to disable skipping in JavaScript console.log()

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm trying to measure time taken by a function to execute in JS.
When I try to `console.log()` the elapsed time, some blue numbers appear in the console and some of the logs are gone.
When I counted the appeared number, it matched with the number of lines of `skipped` log.

[image]

I'm sure you can notice the problem at the right part of screenshot.

I would like the console to show all of the logs.

Is there anything I can do? BTW, the browser is Firefox 58.0b8. (Developer Edition)

Comment: There should be a setting for that in the devtools

Comment: related: [Chrome debugger - how to turn off console.log message grouping?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25706235/1048572)

Comment: There's nothing skipped. These blue numbers are just a shorthand to tell you, that the very same value has been logged x times in a row. It's just a more compact output, than actually printing the same value in x consecutive rows.

Comment: @Bergi That was what I wanted, but Firefox doesn't seem to have that setting. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Thomas I wanted to take a screenshot of the log, but the line wasn't sorted(sometimes 8 lines, sometimes 7 lines...). Anyway, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, if this will serve your purpose but this is a workaround not a solution provided by any browser.

You can add a wrapper `function` for `console.log` like below

```
function logToConsole(number) {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1; 
  console.log(number.toString() + Array(randomNumber).join(" "));
}
```

Here, each time `console.log` is called, it is padded with a random number between 1 and 6. (You can also increase the range, if you feel that there is a chance for error)

Complete example below.

```js
function logToConsole(number) {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1; 
  console.log(number.toString() + Array(randomNumber).join(" "));
}

logToConsole(0.1111);
logToConsole(0.1111);
logToConsole(0.1111);
logToConsole(0.1111);
logToConsole(0.1111);
```

Comment: I appriciate your help. Guess I have no choice...

Comment: Why an errorprone random (that might repeat)? Just use an incrementing counter or toggle a boolean flag.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than do console.log, why don't you write the time to an array a print that at the end of the test?

Comment: Not bad. At least I think so. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are benchmarking methods in console that have very high accuracy. You can use `console.time(key)` and `console.timeEnd(key)`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time

```
// kick off 
console.time('asdf')

// later
console.timeEnd('asdf')

// VM18707:1 asdf: 2077.59716796875ms
```

Even calling timeEnd immediately will yield different results, so it's not likely to have multiple consecutive equal results with a more complex script.

Comment: I couldn't solve the problem with your solution.
Duplicated logs were still shortened.