# Why does this show in web console compiler and how to fix it and find the value

Tags: javascript, console, perspective

This This might sound out of of context but, does anyone know why this 2 is showing, anytime this happens I tends to have wrong data. Is there anyway to see the data that is shown there.

If someone is curious about the code, it is basically a recursive function.

```
  (function postRow() {
        if (state == "run") {
              table.update(update_motor());

        }
        requestAnimationFrame(postRow);
        // setTimeout(postRow, 20);

  })();
```

[The image shows the result I am talking about. The location that "2 appears.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTJfF.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"2"` means that it is a duplicate. You can turn it off in Chrome dev tools by going to Settings > Preferences > Console and uncheck Group similar I believe.

Edited:

Found a similar post, [here is the correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584835/why-does-google-chrome-group-identical-console-log-messages)

Comment: The group similar is unchecked but I still get the same issue.

Comment: Sorry! I found another link where someone else had the same issue.  [This should fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584835/why-does-google-chrome-group-identical-console-log-messages).