# Content Script is injected in every frame but doesn't seem to execute

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy, content-script

I'm writing a chrome extension to manipulate DOM elements in a website.

I have a content script that seems to be blocked somehow from executing in the webpage's iFrames even though it is injected.

```
content.js:

console.log("this script is executed");
chrome.runtime.sendMessage("Hello background.js, I am a frame");
```

Both in the webpage's console and the background.js' console only the first frame is logged.
At first I thought the iFrames were dynamically loaded and therefore the content scripts could not be injected. 
Then I looked at the [JS contexts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWpHG.png) in the console and it seems like the opposite is true:
They **are** injected but not executed.

I also tried accessing the frames via the top frame by:

```
let iFrames = document.getElementsByClassName('js-iframe');
    for (iFrame of iFrames) {
        console.log(iFrame.contentDocument);
        console.log(iFrame.contentWindow);
    }

//null
//Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.webpage.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

What am I missing out?

PS: Of course a solution by executing in the frames themselves would be more preferable but a workaround like the one I tried would be extremely helpful as well.

Comment: `{ "matches": ["https://www.webpage.com/*/*"],
            "js": ["content.js"],
            "all_frames": true,
            "match_about_blank": true,
            "run_at": "document_start"
        }`

Comment: The declaration is fine so the only explanation is [grouping of identical messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584835/why-does-google-chrome-group-identical-console-log-messages) in console.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response, but this is not the problem. I'm also sending requests to the background.js where sender and msg are logged which differ for each request. And there also only the top frame is logged

Comment: `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender) => {
    if (msg === "Hello background.js, I am a frame") {
        console.log("sender:");
        console.log(sender);
        console.log("msg");
        console.log(msg);
        console.log("-----------------");
    }
});`

Is it possible that the frames are loaded dynamically? Would there even be a jsContext for them in the chrome console?

Comment: The background script code looks fine. For content script declared in manifest.json it doesn't matter if the iframes are created dynamically or not. 1) Disable console grouping and/or enable timestamps in devtools. 2) Click the reload icon on the extension card in chrome://extensions page, 3) Reload all tabs.

Comment: Ok I did all of that. Sadly the problem didn't go away. But I noticed that even if I had "all_frames: false" the jsContexts in the chrome console didn't look any [different](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWpHG.png).

Comment: It means you didn't reload the extension or there's a bug in Chrome.

Comment: Anyway, currently the question is unanswerable due to a lack of [MCVE](/help/mcve) that we can try.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway for your help :)

Comment: I don't see how I helped though.

Comment: Assuming you did reload the extension, maybe you're editing the code in the wrong folder, not the one from which the extension is loaded in the browser. You can verify the contents of the manifest by opening chrome-extension://your-extension-id/manifest.json in the address bar.

Comment: If you want to try it: the page is "sneakersnstuff.com". Navigate to a product page. Either the iFrames are dynamically loaded or the scripts are blocked.

Comment: Works for me, just as it should. Like I said, the thing you're describing is impossible unless there's a bug in the browser or in your code.

Comment: I think I found my mistake. Until now I thought that "all_frames=true" for a match means:

if a page with this url is called the js files are executed in all the frames in this page/tab. 

What it **does** mean:
It matches this url even if it was an iFrame in another webpage, doesn't it?

Comment: Yep you got it right now and indeed the names in the API aren't the best.

Answer (score -1):

update the Permission in manifest.json
"permissions": [
    "...",
    "content.js"//something that you want to allow
  ]