# jQuery click event not full working in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I'm using jQuery to make somethings after a click on some elements of my page :

```
$('.news-comment-tablink, #news-comment-count, #fast-travel-sparking').click(function(){
    console.log('test');
});
```

All the three elements are on my page, I see them when analysing my code.

But if I have the 'test' in my console on Firefox on each elements, in Chrome, the 'test' appear only on one of them !

I'm not bad in jQuery, but this time I really don't know what to do...

Can you help ?

Comment: I believe you are using a depreciated functionality. Try this instead: `$(document).on('click','.news-comment-tablink, #news-comment-count, #fast-travel-sparking', function(){`. If it works, I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: @Mech if was was deprecated, then it would not be not obsolete nor removed, but it's not anyway because they decided it would break too much existing code.  `$().click(function` is fine.

Comment: Can you include a [mcve] in a snippet here that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and the code works correctly on Chrome. However on chrome, you will see "Test" only appears once as [Chrome's Console groups similar logs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56224705/1854366).

I assume that would be your issue, you'll see the first call being listed in the console, the second and third would just be grouped in the first log.