# How can I let the Debug Console print something 5 times instead of 1 time in Javascript, Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am new to JavaScript. Is there a way to see the Hello 5 times instead see it showing that it was printed 5 times?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584835/why-does-google-chrome-group-identical-console-log-messages shows how to disable this in the Chrome console. Check the VSCode settings to see if it has something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Disable the setting:

`Debug > Console: Collapse Identical Lines`

> Controls if the debug console should collapse identical lines and
> show a number of occurrences with a badge.

Answer (score -1):

Just put a counter with the console logs to see hello 5 times. Like

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
a.forEach((num) => console.log(num, "hello"))
```